# Regex Pattern using bracket '[]'

Tags: python, regex

How can I separate 
`3[a]2[b4[F]c]` into `3[a]` and `2[b4[F]c]` 

 OR 
`3[a]2[bb]` into `3[a]` and `2[bb]` using `re.split`?

I try the following pattern:

```
(\d+)\[(.*?)\]
```

but the output gives me `3a` and `2b4[F"`.

Comment: For the case of arbitrarily nested brackets, you should consider writing a parser.

Comment: Did you mean like this `(?<=])(?=\d)` ? https://ideone.com/podkLl

Comment: Exactly like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use split, you might assert what is on the left is a `]` and on the right is a digit:

```
(?<=])(?=\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXq0i2/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/podkLl)

Example code

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=])(?=\d)"
strings = [
    "3[a]2[b4[F]c]",
    "3[a]2[bb]"
]

for s in strings:
    print (re.split(r'(?<=])(?=\d)', s))
```

Output

```
['3[a]', '2[b4[F]c]']
['3[a]', '2[bb]']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `re.split` since `re` does not support recursion.

You may match and extract numbers that are followed with nested square brackets using [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```
import regex
s = "3[a]2[b4[F]c]"
print( [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'\d+(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])', s)] )
# => ['3[a]', '2[b4[F]c]']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://rextester.com/MHWD42773)

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` - Group 1:

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `(?:[^][]++|(?1))*` - 0 or more sequences of
  - `[^][]++`  - 1+ chars other than `[` and `]` (possessively for better performance)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?1)` - a subroutine triggering Group 1 recursion at this location
- `]` - a `]` char.